# Remove port 3000 for nodejs in nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, port

I spend 1 day to search all on google and try all the code but it seem like nothing work. 
My server code.

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

I try to replace 3000 by 80 but not work.

I also try to change in etc/nginx/conf/example.com.cof

```
server {
    listen   80;
    upstream project {
    server example.com:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://project;
   }

    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
  }

server {
    listen   80 default_server;

     ...
    }
```

Nothing work.

Please help

Comment: Please, fix code formatting. It's too hard to read, not to say it has incorrect syntax

Comment: Some ports are reserved for system services and daemons. For example, port 80 is reserved for http service in Linux. It's better not to change this port. [Here](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/network-services-ports) is the list of all reserved ports in Linux. Avoid using these ports for your applications.

Comment: It's still incorrect

Answer (score 0):

using port 80 requires sudo privileges

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

Start app using,

```
sudo PORT=80 node app.js
sudo PORT=80 npm start #or like this, depends on your app
```

Comment: Find out which process using it `lsof -i tcp:3000`, and kill it `kill pid`

Comment: Im confusing. Are you tell me to use port 80 or 3000?